# Is there an example of a damage type (cold, fire, lightning, psychic, force, etc) explicity granting cover?

Tags: dnd-5e, damage-types, cover

Wall of force is generally assumed to grant cover because it creates a "wall."  The spell itself does not specifically grant the cover condition to those on either side of the wall.

That means it is the "Force" property of the wall that people are assuming grants cover.   Force is a damage type, rather than a substance.

Is there an example of or specific rule that states damage types are capable of granting cover?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Damage types don't grant cover. In fact:

> **Damage types have no rules of their own,** but other rules, such as damage resistance, rely on the types.

<sup>PHB, pg.196</sup>

If it's "generally assumed" that Wall of Force grants cover it's because:

> Nothing can physically pass through the wall,

Not because of the damage type *"force"*.